# How do I use overwrites on an "on_guild_join" event?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.11

I have code for my Discord bot that when it joins a guild, it sends a message to every channel with an embed introducing itself. However, this makes my ticket command not work because it gives me the error `NoneType has no attribute "id"` error, so I came up with a solution to create a muted role with no permissions to send messages to channels, but I am stuck on making the overwrites. How would I make overwrite permissions on an `on_guild_join` event?

Here is my code:

```py
permissions = ""
overwrites = {
    permissions: discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=False)
}
role2 = await guild.create_roles(name="Muted", overwrites=overwrites)
```

I excepted the overwrites to work, but instead of that I get the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are getting is because [discord.Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild) has no attribute 'create_roles'. Basically, you were trying to use something that didn't exist.
To a create role on a guild, use [Guild.create_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role).

```
role2 = await guild.create_role(name="Muted",
                                 permissions=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False))
```

Read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild) for more info.